# How to bind a DataTable to a WPF DataGrid while filtering the rows and have two-way binding

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataTable that represents a SQL table. The SQL table references itself in a parent/child manner, but only one level (a parent can't have a parent itself)

I want to bind this DataTable to a DataGrid so i can edit the rows on the DataGrid and add new Rows and this should be propagated to the DataTable. So far it's easy.

But now i want to display only the rows that have a parent. From what i understand, if i use a CollectionView to filter the data the changes on the grid won't be propagated to the DataTable. So how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens if you try to set the defaultview Rowfilter?

```
var dv = yourDataTableInstance.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "parentcolumn IS NOT NULL";
```

ItemsSource for the DataGrid is still the datatable but it should be filtered now.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. Though the RowFilter must be "parentcolumn IS NOT NULL", the function ISNULL apparentely takes 2 arguments and either returns the value if it's not null or the second argument if it's null.

Comment: fine. changed the rowfilter like you said